# How to serialize/deserialize from ksql avro format to c# using confluent platform

Tags: c#, serialization, avro, ksqldb, confluent-kafka-dotnet

I am using `KsqlDb` a table with the following form:

**KSQL-DB Query**
`create table currency (id integer,name varchar) with (kafka_topic='currency',partitions=1,value_format='avro');`

**C# model**

```
public class Currency
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Now i want to know how should i write/read data from this topic in C# using the Confluent library:

**Writing**

```
 IProducer<int, Currency> producer=....

 Currency cur=new Currency();

 Message<int,Currency> message = new Message<int, Currency>
            {
                Key = msg.Id,
                Timestamp = new Timestamp(DateTime.UtcNow, TimestampType.CreateTime),
                Value = msg
            };
 DeliveryResult<int,Currency> delivery =  await this.producer.ProduceAsync(topic,message);
```

**Reading**

```
IConsumer<int,Currency> iconsumer = new ConsumerBuilder<int, Currency>(config)
                .SetKeyDeserializer(Deserializers.Int32) //i assume i need to use the id from my dto
                .SetValueDeserializer(...) //what deserializer
                .Build();

ConsumeResult<int,Currency> result = consumer.Consume();

Currency message =  // what deserializer JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Currency>(result.Message.Value);
```

I am not sure how to go about this so i tried looking for serializer. I found this library [AvroSerializer](https://github.com/AdrianStrugala/AvroConvert/blob/master/tests/KafkaApp/Program.cs) , but i do not get where the author fetches the `schema`.

Any help on how to read/write to a specific topic that would match with my `ksqldb` models ?

**Update**

After some research and some answers here i have started using the `schemaRegistry`

```
var config = new ConsumerConfig
            {
                GroupId = kafkaConfig.ConsumerGroup,
                BootstrapServers = kafkaConfig.ServerUrl,
                AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
            };
var schemaRegistryConfig = new SchemaRegistryConfig
            {
                Url = kafkaConfig.SchemaRegistryUrl
            };
var schemaRegistry = new CachedSchemaRegistryClient(schemaRegistryConfig);

IConsumer<int,Currency> consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<int, Currency>(config)
            .SetKeyDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<int>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
            .SetValueDeserializer(new AvroDeserializer<Currency>(schemaRegistry).AsSyncOverAsync())
            .Build();

ConsumeResult<int, Currency> result = consumer.Consume();
```

Now i am getting another error:

> Expecting data framing of length 5 bytes or more but total data size
> is 4 bytes

As someone kindly pointed out it seems i retrieving only the id from the schema registry.

How can i just :  `insert into currency (id,name) values (1,3)` and retrieve it in C# as a POCO (listed above) ?

**Update 2**

After i have found this [source](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/1.7.x/examples/AvroSpecific/Program.cs) program it seems i am not able to publish messages to tables for some reason.

There is no error when sending the message but it is not published to Kafka.

Answer (score 0):

> I found this library AvroSerializer , but i do not get where the author fetches the schema.

Unclear why you need to use a library other than the Confluent one, but they get it [from the Schema Registry](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/develop/api.html). You can use [`CachedSchemaRegistryClient`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/blob/master/src/Confluent.SchemaRegistry/CachedSchemaRegistryClient.cs) to get the schema string easily, however you shouldn't need this in the code as the deserializer will download from the registry on its own.

If you refer to the [`examples/` in the `confluent-kafka-dotnet` repo for Specific Avro consumption](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/master/examples/AvroSpecific), you can see they generate the `User` class from `User.avsc` file, which seems to be exactly what you want to do here for `Currency` rather than write it yourself

Comment: Which library are you referring  as `the Confluent one`. I have not seen an example as to how serialize/deserialize POCO . 
II just want an easy way to just serialize my `POCO` c# model to avro format , insert it to kafka , transform it using `ksql` and then consume from the output topic  and deserialize from  AVRO to another C# model

Comment: [This library from Confluent](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/tree/master/examples/AvroSpecific)  (link to example) - Doesn't define a POCO. It generates it. That library is imported into the one linked in your question, so you'd have it installed, anyway. Also Avro in KSQL requires the Schema Registry which is **not** "plain Avro"

Comment: I have went past that part and now when i am consuming messages it says that the minimum length of bytes is 5 and i receive only 4 from kafka , and then it throws , and i do not get why.

Comment: Like I said, data isn't "plain Avro" - At least 5 bytes are reserved for the Schema Registry data. https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/schema-registry/serdes-develop/index.html#wire-format

Comment: Could you please be more explicit. I do not understand what i must do in order to fetch the entire message.I have updated my original post.

Comment: I do not use C#. I suggest following the README page there linked above first. If you still have issues - report here - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues

Comment: I have followed the readme and now while i can send messages to Kafka , it appears they are not published. Although there is no error on the application side.

Comment: Did you include the `.ContinueWith(task =>` callback? And that didn't execute? I assume you flushed/closed the producer after sending the data (which is done after exiting the `using` block)?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by defining my custom serializer , thus implementing the [`ISerializer<T>`](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/clients/confluent-kafka-dotnet/_site/api/Confluent.Kafka.ISerializer-1.html) and `IDeserializer<T>` interfaces which in their belly are just wrappers over `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` or `NewtonsoftJson`.

**Serializer**

```
public class MySerializer:ISerializer<T>
{
     byte[] Serialize(T data, SerializationContext context)
     {
          var str=System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data); //you can also use Newtonsoft here
          var bytes=Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
          return bytes;
     }
}
```

**Usage**

```
   var config = new ConsumerConfig
                {
                    GroupId = kafkaConfig.ConsumerGroup,
                    BootstrapServers = kafkaConfig.ServerUrl,
                    AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest
                };
    IConsumer<int,Currency> consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<int, Currency>(config)
            .SetValueDeserializer(new MySerializer<Currency>())
            .Build();

ConsumeResult<int, Currency> result = consumer.Consume();
```

**P.S**

I am not even using the schema registry here afteri  implemented the interface